# Может ли быть в процессе два WNDPROC?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Я создаю 2 разных окна(думаю код тут не нужен ибо ничего необычного,просто создание самого простого окна(CreateWindowExA) ),для каждого окна своя функция обработки сообщений WNDPROC.Потом создаю цикл перехвата сообщений:

```
    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(msg));
    while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {

        if (PeekMessage(&msg, Null, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
            continue;
        }
}
```

И получается так, что вызывается WNDPROC того окна которое я первое создал.Как понять, какой WNDPROC будет вызываться в данном цикле? Вообще, я хочу создать в приложении 2 потока с обработкой сообщений разных окон,но я не могу понять как явно указать,какой цикл перехвата сообщений за какое окно будет отвечать

Приложу на всякий случай как я создаю 1 из окон:

```
bool init_window_Esp(const char* windowsName)
{
    strcpy(gameName, windowsName);

    wcEsp = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW, EspWndProc, 0L, 0L, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, NULL, (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)), NULL, _T("Example"), NULL };
    RegisterClassEx(&wcEsp);
    gameHWND = FindWindow(NULL, gameName);
    if (gameHWND == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Not find Game", "ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(gameHWND, &rc);

    cheatEspHWND = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED, wcEsp.lpszClassName, wcEsp.lpszMenuName, WS_POPUP, 1, 1, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, 0, 0, 0, 0);  // |  WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    
    GuiEngine::Esp::init_render();

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(cheatEspHWND, 0, 0, LWA_ALPHA);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(cheatEspHWND, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0), LWA_COLORKEY);

    MARGINS Margin = { -1, -1, -1, -1 };
    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(cheatEspHWND, &Margin);

    ShowWindow(cheatEspHWND, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(cheatEspHWND);
    return 0;
}
```

P.s Я пробовал в PeekMessage указывать явно хендл окна,сообщения которого надо обработать,но все равно вызывается WNDPROC окна которое мы самое первое зарегистрировали в приложении

P.s.s Нашел проблему,у меня классы окон имели одинаковые имена.Теперь вызываются поочередно оба WNDPROC.Но как мне сделать чтоб обрабатывалось 1 конкретное окно а не 2 сразу?Если я указываю в PeekMessage конкретное окно,то у меня все равно обрабатываются сообщения всех окон.

Answer (score 1):

`PeekMessage` или `GetMessage`, конечно, принимают параметр HWND окна, и даже диапазон сообщений.

На самом деле туда следует передавать нули, и не пользоваться всем этим.

Оно не работает по следующим причинам:

- Параметры `PeekMessage` / `GetMessage` управляют диспечеризацией Posted сообщений. Тех, которые они вернут через `&msg`. Есть ещё Sent сообщения, которые отправляются функциями вроде `SendMessage`, и вот эти функции перешлют все `Sent` текущие сообщения до того, как примутся за Posted (третий отдельный вид сообщений -- WM_QUIT сообщение, но оно ближе к Posted)
- Sent сообщения вообще идут через `PeekMessage` / `GetMessage`, если они идут из другого потока выполнения, иначе они (примерно) являются прямым вызовом оконной процедуры
- Попытка выфильтровать нужное окно или нужное сообщение может приводить к тому, что очередь сообщений будет забиваться "ненужным", и потом нужное просто не поместится. У вас же в программе не одно окно. И заранее вы не знаете, какие сообщения должны ходить, хотя бы потому, что есть куча недокументированных сообщений или сообщений сторонних приложений
- Если вызовете какую-нибудь функцию вроде 'MessageBox`, она будет крутить оконный цикл за вас, пропуская все окна и все сообщения.

Из аналогичных соображений всяким `MsgWait...` нужен `QS_ALLINPUT`, использование других, болеее ограничивающих флагов -- не очень хорошая идея.